# Different form of arrays in php and accessing the values

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array, When i use `var_dump` to show the array, i get this output blow :

```
array(2) {
  ["System"]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1111"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2222"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "3333"
  }
  ["test"]=>
  string(2) "on"
}
```

i want to access to every every inner value with using foreach or any code that will work with that code. I mean for example, I want to echo Out something like this :

```
System "1" has "1111" value.
System "2" has "2222" value.
System "3" has "3333" value.
```

So, i tried to use such this code :

```
foreach ($array['System'] as $key => $value) {
    echo 'System "' . $key . '" has "' . $value . '" value.'."<br />\n";
}
```

But, It's **NOT** wordking!

I have this **error** :

> Warning:  Illegal string offset 'System'
>
> > Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

What is my problem? How can i solve?

**I can't change the out put of the array (when i use var_dump)**

Comment: You knew how to use `var_dump()` at the beginning.. keep using that inside your loop on `$key` and `$value` to debug your issue.

Comment: Those errors are coming from a different part of your script. There's no `ans` in the code you posted.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, i changed `ans` to `systems` in code to be seen better. but the error is still coming for any.

Comment: `Illegal string offset` means that `$array` is a string, not an array.

Comment: @user3394468 Please post your actual code because the code you've put will work fine. We can't help if you post different code and show an error for something that isn't here.

Comment: @Barmar yes, is the **array(2)** i wrote at top string you think? I am echoing it with Var_dump

Comment: @user3394468 No `array(2)` means it is an array with two keys ('System' and 'test').

Comment: @BadHorsie My code is actually this, The problem is that The array that is echoing with var_dump is not accessable with that code i think!

Comment: @BadHorsie yes of cource but as you see in this : http://codepad.org/4mUtrJ6L the array is not exactily the same as i have with var_dump

Comment: There are some problems with your var_Dump. Because `string(1) "1111"` should be `string(4)`

Comment: @dynamic i wrote the third part to be seen better

Comment: @user3394468 The part we need to help you is where you define `$array`. Post that code... `$array = ...` There's something not right about the array as you've defined it, but we can't see what that is. Your var_dump should look like this http://codepad.org/jkwI6hkt if your array is defined correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works correctly as you can see here: http://codepad.org/4mUtrJ6L

```
$array = array('System'=>array(
    '1111',
    '2222',
    '3333'
));

foreach ($array['System'] as $key => $value) {
    echo 'System "' . $key . '" has "' . $value . '" value.'."<br />\n";
}
```

Output:

```
System "0" has "1111" value.
System "1" has "2222" value.
System "2" has "3333" value.
```

Your array should be built like this:

```
$array = array('System'=>array('1111','2222','3333'));
```

Also in your snippet, there isn't nothing such as `Warning: Illegal string offset 'ans'`. Maybe the error is somewhere else

Comment: No the array you are using is not exactly the thing i wrote , check it please

Comment: Post the code to build your array then

Comment: my array is build with var_dump, i can't change it

Comment: You cannot "build" an array with var_dump

Comment: So you say the array(2) i wrote is not array?!

Comment: I don't know how your array looks like because you didn't post how you built it.